# How can I parse a bracketed string to a list of string with a given delimitor

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

My task is to parse a bracketed string, like

`[foo | bar | foobar]`, to a `vector` of `std::strings`.

In this case,
the `vector` should end up with the contents `{"foo" , "bar", "foobar"}`.

These brackets can be nested. For example, the given bracketed string

`[[john | doe] | [ bob | dylan]]`

would become `{ "[john | doe]" , "[bob | dylan] }`"

The best I could manage so far is

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const std::string input {argv[1]};
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
     '[' 
     >> *qi::lexeme[ +(qi::char_ - '|')  >> '|'] 
     > -qi::lexeme[ +(qi::char_  - ']') >> ']' ],
     qi::space ,
     res);

    for (const auto& v: res)
        std::cout << v  <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which fails miserably for the nested case. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Note #1: Nested cases can be more than one.

Note #2: I welcome any simpler solutions, even without using Boost Spirit.

Comment: Maybe use a stack data structure that keeps track of how many `[` braces you have encountered? Every time you encounter a `]`, you `push_back` the substring from the last `[` to the last `]` into the final `vector` and then pop the stack.

Comment: Actually, can you explain a bit more about how the `|` and the `[` symbols work?

Comment: Your example is stripping out spaces adjacent to the `|`.  Is that required?  Is a `|` without accompanying spaces a valid separator?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple C++ parser based on the assumption that brackets are balanced, i.e. every `[` has a `]` there.

`bracket` is the number of opening brackets. We make crucial decisions when that number is `1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

bool edge(const int num){
    return num == 1;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> all;
    std::string line;
    // std::getline(std::cin, line);
    line = "[[john | doe] | [ bob | dylan]]";

    int bracket = 0;
    std::string::size_type start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++){
        const char c = line[i];
        if(c == '['){
            bracket++;
            if(edge(bracket)){
                start = i + 1;
            }
        }
        if(c == ']'){
            if(edge(bracket)){
                all.push_back(line.substr(start, i - start));
            }
            bracket--;
        }
        if(c == '|' && edge(bracket)){
            all.push_back(line.substr(start, i - start));
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }
    for(std::string_view t : all){
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "We make crucial decisions when that number is 1."  That would work if you always tested the number inside the brackets.  You could check the number outside the brackets against zero.  (Well not really, because you also have `|` which is purely inside)  Unfortunately your logic is currently testing *before* the bracket, which is half-inside-half-outside and not working.  You want code equivalent to `if(edge(++bracket))` and `if(edge(bracket--))`

Comment: I definitely felt the need to create functions which better indicate the case that we have just one bracket after including current `c`, or zero after including current `c`. // "  and not working" But I had tested before posting.. let me try again.. it could be a last minute rushed change .

Comment: Yes, because you were actually matching on (and including) the *second* bracket of the `[[john | doe] | [ bob | dylan]]` input when the right behavior is to match (and exclude) the outermost bracket.

Answer (score 2):

If you want nested lists of strings, first you'll need a result that can store nested lists. Luckily, in C++17 you can have vectors of forward references (as long as their defined at some point). So you can make a type that is a list, where every item is either a string or another list:

```cpp
struct Expr : std::vector<
    boost::variant<
        std::string,
        Expr>>
{ 
    using std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, Expr>>::vector;
};
```

After the grammar is pretty simple. Note that it's recursive - `Term` can have an `Expr` nested into it:

```
WORD = /[^\[\|\]]+/
Term = WORD | Expr
Expr = '[' Term ('|' Term)* ']';
```

You can express each rule separately. Boost Spirit Qi conveniently has the `%` operator, which parses a delimited list and inserts it into a container.

```cpp
using It = std::string::const_iterator;
using Sk = qi::space_type;
qi::rule<It, std::string(), Sk> word;
qi::rule<It, boost::variant<std::string, Expr>(), Sk> term;
qi::rule<It, Expr(), Sk> expr;

word = +(qi::char_ - '[' - '|' - ']'); 
term = word | expr;
expr = '[' >> (term % '|') >> ']';
```

Then `qi::phrase_parse` will do what you want:

```cpp
Expr res;
qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), expr, qi::space, res);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5W993s

Comment: This code compile with gcc 8.3.1 with -std=c++11.  What actually needs C++17 here ?

Comment: C++17 is needed for a guarantee in the standard that you _can_ describe an `std::vector` with a forward reference. gcc's libstdc++ just happens to implement it that way for C++11, which is fine if it meets your requirements. If not, you can use a vector of `unique_ptr` to itself, but you would have to use Spirit X3 since Qi is not move-aware.

Comment: How could I change the example to return get a std::vector<std::string> ?

Comment: What would be in that vector? Just the first level, or a flattened list of words?

Comment: just the first level.  Idea would be to then call again the parsing function on each element (because the separator may change between each level, for example, "[ [ aa;bb] | [cc;dd] ]"  => would expect to get a vector  {"[aa;bb]" , "[cc;dd]"}  and apply recursively the parsing function on each element changing the separtor from | to ;

Comment: If that's the case, go with @puio's answer. Boost Spirit is too much for just that.

Answer (score 0):

This simpler version seems to be what you want:

```
qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
    '[' 
    >> qi::lexeme[ +~qi::char_("|]") ] % '|' 
    >> ']',
    qi::space,
    res);
```

It will parse:

```
"foo "
"bar "
"foobar"
```

Maybe you didn't actually want the spaces as part of the matches. Then it can be even simpler:

```
qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
    '[' 
    >> qi::lexeme[ +(qi::graph - qi::char_("|]")) ] % '|' 
    >> ']',
    qi::space,
    res);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9670d61ab405bd75)**

> Note: if you have C++14 consider using X3: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a797036a963a0612). That will be a lot faster to compile

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems this solution does not work in the nested case(s).